# htaccess redirect any urls ending in .php to index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've set up my .htaccess so far as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

My index.php loads the file from /pages, eg. index.php?page=home will load the page content from pages/home.php

However - if someone went to pages/home.php the page loads without the headers etc. which is undesirable. What can I add to redirect any URLs ending in .php to just take the user to the homepage?

Thanks

Comment: `Deny From All` in the .htacess placed in the pages directory will solve your problem at once

Comment: I'd rather be afraid of include injection in this code...

Comment: Deny from All - that's done the trick. When you say include injection - could you be more specific please? Thanks

Comment: if you are doing just `include $_GET['page']` it is possible to include some malicious script. At least sanitize your filename using `basename()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate RewriteRule (without file exists condition) for `^(.*)\.php$` should work. But why are people trying to access the .php directly? If there isn't a good reason, a Deny in the directory is probably a better bet.

(And, as @Col. Shrapnel comments, beware include injection. I hope you're filtering your page names well.)

edit: include injection: Consider what happens if someone gives you an interesting page name, such as `page=http://foo.com/exploit`, will your script run it? What about `page=/etc/passwd` or `page=/../../../etc/passwd`, will you print out the password file? `` page=`mysqldump …` ``, will you give a copy of your database?

Comment: I've gone for the Deny from all - sorts the problem. Thanks

Comment: @include injection edit: Ah don't worry I've got that covered - making use of basename() and file_exists(). There's no chance of sql injection either :)
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This should redirect `pages/anything.php` to `index.php?page=anything`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

note the security tips above. include injection is bad..