# .htaccess redirect all .html pages to process.php with get parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all links that have .html extension to a process.php file with directory + page name as get parameter. I have tried these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670997/htaccess-redirect-all-html-pages-to-php-get-variables)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619726/htaccess-redirect-any-urls-ending-in-php-to-index?rq=1) solution but it does not work.

for e.g

```
http://localhost/Site/directory1/test1.html
http://localhost/Site/directory2/test2.html
```

to redirected to process.php as

```
http://localhost/Site/process.php?directory1/test1.html
http://localhost/Site/process.php?directory2/test2.html
```

I have tried like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html /process.php?page=$1
```

and this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]*)\.php$ /process.php?page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

but it does not work.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a question. What is the webroot directory? What is the full path of the .htaccess file? Please enable rewrite logging and copy from the log to show what mod_rewrite does *instead*. Also you are using the wrong terms. Your question has nothing to do with redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /$1/process.php?page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @zerkms This will result to: `http://localhost/Site/process.php?page=directory1/test1.html`, isn't what the OP wants?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /index.php?page=$1/$2 [R=301,L]` This is working fine thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is very close to what I believe your looking for. Your just off by one directory and your looking for .php when you should be looking for .html. Give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ /Site/process.php?$2/$3 [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do(assuming that the .htaccess file lives in the `Site` directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*?/)?(.*)$ /$1/process.php?page=$2 [R=301,L]
```